# Update Only 1 Row While loop Mistake

Tags: php, mysql, sql, while-loop, sql-update

I'm still new to writing querys to mysql ad PHP, so I'm sure it is a newbie mistake, but I can't figure it out.

When I display Variables with Echo those are Display With Different Value But When I tried to Update It's Update ONLY ONE ROW.

After It's Say Error :- Duplicate entry '654-657' for key 'PRIMARY'

I Have Problem With While LOOP but don't know Where

Any Help Will be appreciate.

```
    <?php

        $index = 0;

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($find))
        {


//Take Row Value with , from "Ratings" tables and Store In Variable

              $rating_exp = $row['ratings'];
    echo "<br />Orignal Rating = $rating_exp<br />";          
// Use EXPLODE function to store String Value In ARRAY Very Most IMP Step.            

              $rating_exp =  explode(',', $rating_exp);

//Take First element of the arrray And Store In Variable.

                $First_element_array =   array_shift(array_values($rating_exp));

//Make array values = First element value Untill Array = 4.

                $sum = 0; //Declare Variable to Store SUM value.

                for($i = 0; $i<4 ; $i++)
            {
                //Create Array With First Element Value For 4 step.
                //Store in Array
                $rating_exp[$i] = $First_element_array; 
                $sum+=$First_element_array;
            }

//Convert Array to the String With , Use Function implode.

                $string = implode(',', $rating_exp);




            echo "<br />---------------------------------<br />";   
//Store Values in Database For Update Rating Table

            $update_rating_id = $row['rating_id'];
            $update_reviewid = $row['reviewid'];
            $update_ratings = $string;
            $update_ratings_sum = $sum;
            $update_ratings_qty = 4;

            echo "update_rating_id     $update_rating_id <br />";
            echo "update_reviewid      $update_reviewid <br />";
            echo "update_ratings       $update_ratings <br />";
            echo "update_ratings_sum   $update_ratings_sum <br />";
            echo "update_ratings_qty   $update_ratings_qty <br />";
            echo "<br />---------------------------------<br />";
            echo "---------------------------------<br />";

     $Update_Rating = "UPDATE Ratings R JOIN Comment C ON C.id = R.reviewid    SET  R.rating_id = '$update_rating_id',R.reviewid='$update_reviewid', R.ratings='$update_ratings', R.ratings_sum ='$sum',R.ratings_qty='$update_ratings_qty' where C.pid = 763";
     $Update_Rating1 = mysql_query($Update_Rating);
     if (!$Update_Rating1) die("Query failed: $Update_Rating\n" . mysql_error());


        $index++;

        }

        echo "<br /><br />Total Updated Records = $index<br />";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will only update one row every time since the Update statement has `where C.pid = 763`

Should this be something like `where C.pid = $pid` ?

Also your `$string = implode(',', $rating_exp);` is always going to have 4 of the first item in the array. The for loop before it assigns the "First_element_array" to the first 4 slots in the array, then converts that to a string..

--- Update for solution from comments:

The update query matches multiple rows to be updated, however, the ratings_id is a primary key. Therefore, it will successfully update the first row, then fail on the second row because it will try to update the primary key to have the same value that we just set in the first row.

Comment: So this is then updating the primary keys in the ratings table for multiple rows with the same values? Is either R.rating_id or R.reviewid a primary key?

Comment: R.rating_id is Primary Key

Comment: @krishkim - "C.pid = 763" will match multiple rows and then the update statement will set the first row's R.rating_id with the new value. The second row update will fail because there is already a R.rating_id with that same value (the first row updated).

Answer (score 0):

If Someone Need In future.

```
  $Update_Rating = "UPDATE Ratings R JOIN Comment C ON C.id = R.reviewid    SET  R.rating_id = '$update_rating_id',R.reviewid='$update_reviewid', R.ratings='$update_ratings', R.ratings_sum ='$sum',R.ratings_qty='$update_ratings_qty' where C.id = $update_reviewid";
```